# centos 6.5 ssh rsa key fails

Tags: centos, ssh, rsa, freepbx

Alright I have read many many articles and followed a few different tutorials and I can not get my RSA key to work on my centos servers. The servers are running centos 6.5 with FreePBX on them and I am trying to get this to work from my Ubuntu VM on my laptop so we can build a central server to ssh from so I can run scripts to change things on all servers with minimal work since we have over 70 of these servers so far and rising quickly but it won't work.  I have stared out some the log but those parst don't need to be displayed n the public internet but the user is the root user (not just a sudoer but the root user)

```
mitch@ubuntu:~$ ssh -v ******@*******.com
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ********.com [***.***.***.***] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/mitch/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/mitch/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mitch/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /home/mitch/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mitch/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mitch/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mitch/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mitch/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA ************************************************
debug1: Host '*********.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/mitch/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/mitch/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/mitch/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mitch/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mitch/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
******@************.com's password:
```

Comment: Your client offered `/home/mitch/.ssh/id_rsa` and `.../id_dsa` to the server, but the server didn't accept them. You'll need to troubleshoot this on the server. What did you do to the server for it to accept these these keys?

Comment: I put the keys in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and did a `chmod 700 /.ssh` and a `chmod 600 /.ssh/authorized_keys`

I tried running `restorecon -Rv ~ /. ssh`

I also tried copying the keys to `etc /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` as recommended by /etc/ssh/sshd_config even though that directory did not exist.

Comment: Check the logs on the server.

Comment: `Oct  5 15:40:56 sp69 sshd[16774]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/******` and that directory shows `drwxr-xr-x  3      503`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry in advance for my English, as it's not my first language :)

First, mount your remote shared folder, for example, in /root/.ssh/

Still on your central server, create your key's like this :

ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "user@remotehost"

It will ask you the following :

Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa):

Type something like :

/root/.ssh/NameOfSSHKeyFile

I strongly suggest you to choose a strong password, different for each key's.  Use a good local password manager.

In order to login using the ssh key, ON THE REMOTE SERVER you need to add your public key in this file :

/root/.ssh/authorized_keys

The public key is usually in the ~/.ssh/  folder, and the file extension is .pub (so should be /root/.ssh/NameOfSSHKeyFile.pub if you followed my examples)

Then, chmod the files :

chmod 400 ~/.ssh/*

**If it still doesn't work :**

Seems like you may require to add the key to your ssh wallet.  It only searched for your ssh key in theses files

ebug1: identity file /home/mitch/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/mitch/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mitch/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /home/mitch/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mitch/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mitch/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mitch/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mitch/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1

...but it didn't found it.

Let's add the key to wallet then :

```
ssh-add .ssh/NameOfSSHKeyFile
```

Voilà :)

Oh! and for better security :

```
ssh-add -D
```

...is going to remove the key's from your wallet.  Please use it :

You are always better to do this after each intervention.

And don't forget once you created the .pub file, you no longer require to keep it on your Central Server : the .pub key file need to be on the remote server only.

Delete it once it's in the authorized_keys file on the remote server.

You can also restrict your ssh keys per ip.  On the remote server, in /root/.ssh/authorized_keys, you can add from="" to restrict usage of your key on a per ip basis :

It would give something like :

```
from="CENTRA-SERVER-IP-ADDRESS" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDHvpIcRLrfmdRb+cK48ooYYLNddaayE5hG5KmHsASKork/T1MvRB3WQJOvJetkM2v7H2G76w90Gr5QpbBhCAD2BqOpIeUKo+npmmUASn48QUs4YzhYbkyRwGWOfrYiKl8oBk2ZXcEV6cL1bHH96OMrozKjrMer6JddvJEAqEEJjny0lg5j/raaDpoEXvPE8YM/oQcs64RUJWp3LwmFR8VO/mSLFSFbuulVDALPWICoWZ/VxE7mR9QhNBlY9Afwe//LDtitPg3eG1hoNLBHbxHpjImBt1ZdaQE4w0y4Nh07Q6E8aepYqNJsdFMZJERL58qGOYvnGTweOLZhtYQa+xNF test
```

Comment: That would have worked to it looks like, however I was trying to keep it out of the root directory.... Now I just have to see if I can mount a shared folder to the machine on a different server that will contain the keys! So I can manage the keys in one place.

Comment: Just mount the shared folder in /root/.ssh

Comment: ...or any other folder, in fact. If you mount the shared folder in /home for example, then ssh-add /home/path/to/ssh/key